# Como selecionar um registro específico de um array

Tags: javascript

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema. Criei dinamicamente um array para receber algumas informações. 
`selections
[2]{"2","alt-2-2"} 
[7]{"3","alt-7-3"} 
[8]{"1","alt-8-1"}`

Bem, na chave eu gravo a id no banco de dados desse registro, em seguida é registrado a opção escolhida entre 1 e 3 e na última qual a id da div que foi escolhida. Podem perceber que a id da div é composta por "alt-id_no_mysql-opcao_escolhida". Só que agora digamos que apenas a opção 3 seja, correta, apenas a chave 7 está certa, e as demais estão erradas. Como faço pra navegar no array buscando qual está correta? Sei que se as chaves fossem sequenciais tipo 0,1,2... um for já resolvia, como faço nesse caso então?

Comment: Acho que é isso que está querendo: var valor = meuArray.find(x => x == 'alt-2-2');

Comment: @MarceloVieira essa função find() retorna somente aquela que estiver verdadeira. Mas posso ter dezenas de verdadeiras dentro desse array

Comment: Mas você quer retornar todas as que tem a opção escolhida é isso ? Ou seja se tiver um "alt-7-3" e outro "alt-1-3" e for a opção "3" tem que devolver os 2 ?

Comment: @Isac exatamente

Comment: Esse seu `selections` é um array ou objeto ? O que está lá dentro é objeto ou array ? Se for objeto quais são as chaves ? Tem como por um exemplo que compile do seu `selections` ?

Comment: O "selections" é um array. Daí eu preciso registrar o que foi selecionado. Como a mudança pode ser realizada antes de salvar fiz assim:  `selections[id_no_db] = opcao_selecionada; selections[id_no_db] = id_da_div;`

Comment: Daí se houver mudanças ele sempre vai sobrescrever na chave da id. Só que essas id variam conforme a situação.

Comment: e o que está dentro de cada posição do `selections` ? `{"2","alt-2-2"}` não é um objeto valido. Tem como mostrar um `console.log(selections)` ?

Comment: (7) [empty × 2, Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]2: ["2", index: 4, input: "alt-2-2", groups: undefined]3: ["1", index: 4, input: "alt-1-3", groups: undefined]4: ["1", index: 4, input: "alt-1-4", groups: undefined]5: ["2", index: 4, input: "alt-2-5", groups: undefined]6: ["3", index: 4, input: "alt-3-6", groups: undefined]length: 7__proto__: Array(0)
temp1
(7) [empty × 2, Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]

Comment: Ainda não consegui perceber exatamente o que tem em cada posição, que parece ser objetos específicos de uma classe que você tem. `selections[2].input` dá lhe `"alt-2-2"` ? Como foi construído esse `selections` ? Se conseguir colocar um exemplo de como construiu isso, posso colocar a resposta com um exemplo a funcionar, senão fica mais difícil.

Comment: Apenas declarei ela. var selections = [] ; Depois eu já uso ela lançando a id e o selected como informei um pouco acima

Comment: @AlessandroCarvalho consegue colar aqui o trecho de código que realiza o lançamento? digamos que seja `selections[1] = objetoQueEstaInserindo;` Oque eu queria saber mais precisamente seria o retorno do `console.log(objetoQueEstaInserindo);`